# How to traverse a list and drop a value incrementally

Tags: haskell

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [1,2,6,3,9]
```

I want to write a function that sums all the numbers in the list and appends this value to a new list, then walk through the list and drop a value one by one and sum the values. The function would perform this computation:

```
result = [[1+2+6+3+9],
          [1+6+3+9],
          [1+2+3+9],
          [1+2+6+9],
          [1+2+6+3]]
```

The function I am trying to describe would produce this result given the list example above:

> [21,19,15,18,12]

I am having a difficult time understanding how to implement this function in Haskell. Specifically, how to traverse a list, and drop one element but increment the dropped value by one each time. Can anyone help? Thanks. I've been trying to write a helper function that uses a fold, but I can't figure out how to drop a different element from the last upon each "iteration".

Comment: I don't understand how you get from `lst` to `result`. Why is the first element of `result` the sum of six numbers, when all the other elements are the sum of five numbers? Why does `3` appear twice in most of the sums? It only appears once in `lst`.

Comment: Opps, typo. I've fixed it now. Essentially sum all the values then sum all the values, but remove one value prior to summation. Do not remove the first value. Make sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could write something along those lines:

```
f xss@(x:xs) = total : map (total -) xs
  where total = sum xss
```

Basically it says that first you have the sum of your list, then you have for each element this same sum minus this element (and we skip the head).

For more details:

- `(x:xs)` is used to pattern match on the given list, so that we can easily skip the head later by only using `xs`
- `xss@...` is used to name the whole pattern so that we can still use the whole list easily
- the where clause introduces a variable that holds the sum of the list, this way it's not recalculated plenty of times (maybe it'd have been optimized anyway, this way we're sure).
- `(total -)` is an operator section: when called with argument `x`, it'll return `total - x`

Note: you'd have to precise what happens when this function is given the empty list, for example, if you want it to return the empty list, add:

```
f [] = []
```

**edit**: explanations about `map (total -) xs`:

as I detailed in my list above, `(total -)` is an operator section that gives us the following function:

```
\x -> total - x
```

it returns the total minus the value it's given.

Now, we map that function on the tail of the list given to `f`. For example, if you give `f` the list

```
[1, 2, 6, 3, 9]
```

It'll me mapped over

```
[2, 6, 3, 9]
```

If total is `21`, the result of the map call is

```
[19, 15, 18, 12] -- [21 - 2, 21 - 6, 21 - 3, 21 - 9]
```

Comment: I get some of this function, but I don't understand the `map (total -) xs` part. Can you explain this futher. Thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: Thanks Mog! I appreciate you taking the time to expand your answer. Haskell is tough, but I think I'm slowly starting to understand it.

Answer (score 9):

Mog has given an answer that exploits the fact that `(+)` is associative, commutative, and has an inverse. However, I think it's also constructive to give an answer that works for any operation; that is, to produce the actual lists you're summing, then sum them. So the plan will be like this:

1. Write a function that splits a list at each possible position.
2. Write a function that turns a split back into a list by dropping the element at the split.
3. Write a function that sums a list (already done in `Prelude`: use the `sum` function).
4. Write a function that combines them, and includes the special case of the entire list.

There's a couple ways to do part one. The first choice is explicit recursion:

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits []     = [([],[])]
splits (x:xs) = ([],x:xs) : map (\(b,e) -> (x:b,e)) (splits xs)
```

We can check it out in ghci to make sure we've got it right:

```
*Main> splits "abcde"
[("","abcde"),("a","bcde"),("ab","cde"),("abc","de"),("abcd","e"),("abcde","")]
```

However, there's a nicer way. The `Data.List` module includes a bunch of functions for munging lists in particular ways. Two of them are `tails` and `inits`:

```
*Main> tails "abcde"
["abcde","bcde","cde","de","e",""]
*Main> inits "abcde"
["","a","ab","abc","abcd","abcde"]
```

So this definition is much nicer looking:

```
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Now, we want a function that produces the list of lists with one element dropped from each position.

```
dropEach xs = [beginning ++ end | (beginning, ignored:end) <- splits xs]
```

So the final step is to put everything together.

```
funnySums xs = map sum (xs : dropEach xs)
```

We can test:

```
*Main> funnySums [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
[11111,11110,11101,11011,10111,1111]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful and very clear. I greatly appreciate the tutaliage! I didn't know about tails and inits!